# Debugging an Android app in Eclipse using the handset

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, mobile

I am just starting to learn Android development using the Android SDK and Eclipse. I can get my HelloWorld starting app to run in the device emulator, but not on my Verizon Droid handset. I have downloaded the drivers for Windows 7 and I can see the files on the handset in Windows Explorer, so I'm assuming I have the drivers working. I have enabled the USB Debugging on the handset.

The problem is that when I set the Debug mode to Manual in Eclipse, I do not see my device in the "Choose device" list.  What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem is here...want to debug an android app in eclipse using the HTC Hero

Comment: Normally I point at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html, but it sounds like you already have the Windows setup done.  Can you issue "adb" commands from a command line?

Answer (score 0):

Before you connect the handset, do you have the handset drivers installed on the PC? If so, without running the Eclipse if you connect the handset to PC, does a pop up show up on bottom right saying "your drivers are installed and your device is ready to use"? (assuming windows development environment)

Before developing/testing on handset you should be able to seamlessly establish handset and PC connectivity. Only then will you be able to use handset for Android development.

Comment: I do not get any pop up saying that the device is ready. I can enable the usb storage device on the handset. I also have USB debugging turned on. I do see the Droid handset as a removeable drive in Windows and can see the files on the handset.
But, I still do not see the handset in Eclipse.

Comment: Try this, connect the handset to PC, go to "C:\<ANDROID-INSTALLATION-FOLDER>\tools" and type "adb devices". If you see a handset under "list of devices attached", then you handset is being recognized, its its a connectivity/driver problem.

Comment: what if you don't see it.. What if there's nothing listed, but you can see the hardware in windowsExplorer

Comment: One more thing to do is to set the handset for USB debugging in the handsets Setting -> Applications menu. and then reconnect the handset. Also, you can try killing adb and restarting it with "adb kill-server", adb start-server" commands.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing Samsung Kies. When installing Kies, it utomatically install the drivers for your device.I faced the similar issue before insatalling kies, after installing it.my problem is slved, i am able to see the device in eclipse in DDMS perspective.